# PowerBI UseRelationship in Table Visual

Tags: powerbi, relationship

I'm having a challenge with a requirement in PowerBI that seems like it should have been solved by someone but I cannot find an answer to.

We have a tabular data model set up where there are multiple relationships between tables, through other tables.  Specifically we have a Calendar table that has a relationship with a "Placements" table through "Placement.dateAdded."  Calendar also has a relationship with a "JobOrders" table through "JobOrders.DateAdded."  But Jobs and Placements are related to each other through "Job ID."  This is because a Placement occurs on a Job, but we may need to count jobs that were added during a specific time frame, or Placements that occured during specific time frames.

[image]

For any measure where we count Jobs or Placements, this is not an issue as we use "UseRelationship" to indicate when to use the Placement-CalendarDate relationship or the Jobs-CalendarDate relationship.

Here's a table of counts... and the measure behind it using "useRelationship"
[image]
[image]

The problem I'm having is that our users want to have a drill-down table listing the specific jobs or placements from a cell in the counts tablelike this:
[image]

When we create a table with the rows from Jobs or Placements, there doesn't seem to be a way to choose the relationship to use.  As a result the Placement detail is returning results where the JobOrders.DateAdded is in the date range, not the Placement Date as it should be since the default active relationship is between the Calendar and JobOrders table.

Anyone aware of a fix for this?  Thanks.

Comment: I would have expected a setting on the page (like a filter) or a visual setting to choose the relationship to use.  :-/

Answer (score 1):

We found our own answer on this one.  Sharing it out should anyone else ever have the same need.

The solution appeared to be to stick one of the aggregate measures, with the UseRelationship method in the DAX, in as one of the columns of the table.  It provides no found, since the count for each row is simply "1," but it appears to force the records to use the right relationship.  Then we hide the column.